# Set explicit Id in Doctrine2-Entity while testing without flushing or setId()

Tags: doctrine-orm

I use Entities with

```
id:
    id:
        type: string
        length: 36
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: UUID
```

so I have no *setId()*-Method. While testing, this is how I create my entities:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setFirsname('Foo');
...
$manager->persit($person);
// no flush
```

I tried

```
$metadata = $manager->getClassMetaData('Acme\Entities\Person');
$metadata->setIdGenerator(new AssignedGenerator());

$person = new Person();
....
```

but it said it's missing an assigned ID, but I can't set it without *setId()* (and I don't want *setId()* in my entities).

Comment: Yep.  It's not going to be set until you flush.  You could use Reflection to set it directly.  Or even the Symfony PropertyAccess component.  But you would be better off adjusting your tests so they don't need the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a litte bit with Generators, and tried this:

```
...
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;

class AutoIncGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{

    public $count = 0;

    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $this->count++;
        return $this->count;
    }
}
```

It works exactly the way I need it. Every object has an id (auto inc) with an exclusive number range.

No *flush()* or *setId()* required.